# How do I get then filter XML from a SQL Server 2000 DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, sql-server-2000

I have a table in SQL Server 2000 with a text field containing XML that I need to display on a C# ASP.NET 2.0 page. I need to retrieve the XML and then filter out a list of about 80 possible elements (or white list 20 possible elements to keep might be better).

I can pull the xml out of the DB and display it on my .aspx page, but I am not sure how to filter out any elements first.

Example XML

```
<Message> 
  <MessageNumber>
    1234
  </MessageNumber> 
  <MessageType>
    Auto Notice
  </MessageType> 
  <UPMessageNumber>
    5501
  </UPMessageNumber> 
  <MessageID>
    121223
  </MessageID> 
  <ResponseTo>
    654321
  </ResponseTo>
  <DateTime>
    2010-11-10 09:35:00
  </DateTime>
</Message>
```

In this case I will need to filter out the `UPMessageNumber` and `MessageID` before displaying it on the page.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [XSLT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms767587(VS.85).aspx) to transform input XML into a modified output.

C# example [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307322).

> This step-by-step article shows you
>   how to apply an Extensible Stylesheet
>   Language (XSL) Transformation (XSLT)
>   to an Extensible Markup Language (XML)
>   document by using the XslTransform
>   class to create a new XML document.
>   XSL is an XML-based language that is
>   designed to transform one XML document
>   into another XML document or an XML
>   document into any other structured
>   document.

The previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321860/how-to-remove-elements-from-xml-using-xslt-with-stylesheet-and-xsltproc) addresses directly how to construct XSL for element stripping.

I think the XSL you need is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" priority="10">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="UPMessageNumber | MessageID" priority="20">
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first `xsl:template` copies all nodes by default.  The second omits the named elements.

Comment: So my question on this would be how do I transform the XML when it is not a file? I have this as an XML object, but I am not finding where to add the reference to the xsl to the object. If it was a file, I could just add the "xml-stylesheet" tag.

Comment: @zk - you can use `XslCompiledTransform.Transform` directly on an `XmlDocument` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163434.aspx - let me know if you get stuck (or post a new question on this)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in a simplistic way, you could leverage the DataSet class to read your xml, and then use a Data View Filter.

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(@"C:\so.xml");
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
    dv.RowFilter = "Your Row Filter" //"MessageNumber<>4567" or construct a filter using //a helper
    //Bind dv to grid ??
```

Again once you have your data in a dataset you can do all kinds of things, like selective display of columns, I'm not sure if you wanted to filter the data from a query perspective or "hide" data from view with it still being present

Comment: fyi I read the xml from a file, I saw you're getting your data from a db, still you can get the underlying xml into a dataset fyi