# How to copy everything as is and only remove a specific element

Tags: xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Emp:Employee xmlns:Emp="http://Emp.com">
    <Emp:EmpName>XYZ</Emp:EmpName>
    <Emp:EmpAddres>AAAA</Emp:EmpAddres>
    <Det:EmpDetails xmlns:Det="http://Det.com">
        <Det:EmpDesignation>SE</Det:EmpDesignation>
        <Det:EmpExperience>4</Det:EmpExperience>
    </Det:EmpDetails>
</Emp:Employee>
```

I am just trying to copy all the elements including the namespace but without `<Det:EmpExperience>4</Det:EmpExperience>`

so the final output should be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Emp:Employee xmlns:Emp="http://Emp.com">
        <Emp:EmpName>XYZ</Emp:EmpName>
        <Emp:EmpAddres>AAAA</Emp:EmpAddres>
        <Det:EmpDetails xmlns:Det="http://Det.com">
            <Det:EmpDesignation>SE</Det:EmpDesignation>
         </Det:EmpDetails>
    </Emp:Employee>
```

I used

```
<xsl:template match='/'>
<xsl:copy-of select='@*[not(Det:EmpExperience)]'/>
</xsl:template>
```

its not working :-( ... any solution for this plz.

how to remove only `<Det:EmpExperience>` element and copy rest of the elements including namespace ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove elements from xml using xslt with stylesheet and xsltproc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321860/how-to-remove-elements-from-xml-using-xslt-with-stylesheet-and-xsltproc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321860/how-to-remove-elements-from-xml-using-xslt-with-stylesheet-and-xsltproc/322079#322079)):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:Det="http://Det.com">

 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Det:EmpExperience"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The second template overrides the [identity transformation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) and the empty template uses your matching logic (selecting `Det:EmpExperience` nodes).

Comment: @Madhu CM - note that I forgot the `xmlns:Det="http://Det.com"` declaration in my answer earlier. Updated and tested...