# XSL: adding a new element to all

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm a newbie at XSL/XSLT. I'm trying to add a new element (datasources) to all users elements of this xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<users>
    <user id="1">
        <repo>r1</repo>
        <home>h1</home>
    </user>
    <user id="2">
        <repo>r2</repo>
        <home>h2</home>
    </user>
    <user id="3">
        <repo>r3</repo>
        <home>h3</home>
    </user>
    <user id="4">
        <repo>r4</repo>
        <home>h4</home>
    </user>
    <user id="5">
        <repo>r5</repo>
        <home>h5</home>
    </user>
</users>
```

I'm using this XSL script:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="configXml"/>
    <!-- Copy everything -->
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/users/user[*]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:element name="datasources"></xsl:element>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that in the final result **the id of all users disappear**:

```
<users>
<user>
    <repo>r1</repo>
    <home>h1</home>
    <datasources/>
</user>
<user>
    <repo>r2</repo>
    <home>h2</home>
    <datasources/>
</user>
    <user>
    <repo>r3</repo>
    <home>h3</home>
    <datasources/>
</user>
    <user>
    <repo>r4</repo>
    <home>h4</home>
    <datasources/>
</user>
    <user>
    <repo>r5</repo>
    <home>h5</home>
    <datasources/>
</user>
```

How can I keep the users id in the output?

Comment: FYI `<xsl:element name="datasources"></xsl:element>` is the same as `<datasources />`. You don't need to use `<xsl:element>` to create elements with fixed names.

Answer (score 2):

Your copy everything template needs to be:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

See [How to copy everything as is and only remove a specific element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364409/how-to-copy-everything-as-is-and-only-remove-a-specific-element).

What is happening is that your 2nd template is matching the `<user>` elements but the `<apply-templates/>` will not use the 1st template on attributes since they do not match `node()`

As Ian Roberts points out, you also need to explicitly select `@*|node()` in your `<xsl:apply-templates/>` of your 2nd template in order for attributes to be processed too - in which case they would then be picked up by the modified 1st template.

So the full solution is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="configXml"/>
    <!-- Copy everything -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/users/user[*]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:element name="datasources"></xsl:element>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `<xsl:apply-templates/>` with no `select` is equivalent to `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>`, which does _not_ include attributes. You need to specifically select `@*|node()` if you want attributes as well as child nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The attributes are not copied because you haven't copied them - following the pattern of the other templates, in your `/users/user[*]` template you need to add a

```
<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
```

as the first thing in the `<xsl:copy>` before applying templates to children.