# how to get required tag value from an xml file in .xsl file?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following type of file contains in xml format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <serviceImpl category="default">
        <package>esterMemoryManagement</package>
        <service singleton="true">
            <provides>xoc.hw.cor.memgt.ZContentType</provides>
            <brief>This sis first sdrevice</brief>
        </service>
    </serviceImpl>
    <serviceImpl category="default">
        <package>w.cor.TesterM</package>
        <service singleton="true">
            <provides>xoc.hw.ZAccessTypeProvid</provides>
            <brief>This sis first sdrevice</brief>
        </service>
    </serviceImpl>
</root>
```

i have to get all values within tag `<provides></provides>` in .xsl file. How can i do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't see any XML in your question. Additionally, it's totally unclear what you want to do. I strongly recommend that you rephrase the question, or remove it.

Comment: @MarcoS, looking via the `|edit|` button helps :-)

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the shortest solution that is also completely "push style".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="serviceImpl"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="serviceImpl">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="service"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="service">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="provides"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="provides">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You may also want to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790031/xslt-how-to-keep-only-wanted-elements-from-xml), and related answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a short and complete solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="provides">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <serviceImpl category="default">
        <package>esterMemoryManagement</package>
        <service singleton="true">
            <provides>xoc.hw.cor.memgt.ZContentType</provides>
            <brief>This sis first sdrevice</brief>
        </service>
    </serviceImpl>
    <serviceImpl category="default">
        <package>w.cor.TesterM</package>
        <service singleton="true">
            <provides>xoc.hw.ZAccessTypeProvid</provides>
            <brief>This sis first sdrevice</brief>
        </service>
    </serviceImpl>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
xoc.hw.cor.memgt.ZContentType
xoc.hw.ZAccessTypeProvid
```

**Explanation**:

1. **The only template that produces the result is** the one matching `provides`.
2. **The second template matches any text node and has an empty body**, which effectively overrides the XSLT built-in template for text nodes and prevents ("deletes") any matched text node from being output (an action that otherwise would have been performed by the XSLT built-in template).

Answer (score 0):

You can use XSL to filter out values like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//serviceImpl/provides" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="serviceImpl/provides">
    <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
    <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(btw, Your example XML is not correct in all places)