# Keep XML fields and one child using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, lxml

I am trying to trim an XML document into a new XML document.  I have the following XML:

```
<rpc-reply>
  <configuration changed-seconds="1450987515" changed-localtime="2015-12-24 20:05:15 UTC">
    <routing-instances>
      <instance>
        <name>SOMENAME</name>
        <instance-type>virtual-router</instance-type>
        <interface>
          <name>lo0.1</name>
        </interface>
        <protocols>
          <bgp>
            <group>
              <name>EBGP-TEST</name>
              <type>external</type>
              <neighbor>
                <name>1.1.1.1</name>
                <peer-as>7222</peer-as>
              </neighbor>
            </group>
          </bgp>
          <ospf>
            <area>
              <name>0.0.0.0</name>
              <comment>SOME COMMENT</comment>
              <interface>
                <name>all</name>
              </interface>
            </area>
          </ospf>
        </protocols>
      </instance>
    </routing-instances>
  </configuration>
  <cli>
    <banner>[edit]</banner>
  </cli>
</rpc-reply>
```

This is what I need:

```
<rpc-reply>
  <configuration changed-seconds="1450987515" changed-localtime="2015-12-24 20:05:15 UTC">
    <routing-instances>
      <instance>
        <name>SOMENAME</name>
        <protocols>
          <ospf>
            <area>
              <name>0.0.0.0</name>
              <comment>SOME COMMENT</comment>
              <interface>
                <name>all</name>
              </interface>
            </area>
          </ospf>
        </protocols>
      </instance>
    </routing-instances>
  </configuration>
</rpc-reply>
```

Here is the XSLT code I am using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="match:ns" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <ns:WhiteList>
   <name>area</name>
   <name>interface</name>
   <name>instance</name>
   <name>metric</name>
  </ns:WhiteList>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(descendant-or-self::*[name()=document('')/*/ns:WhiteList/*])]"/>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And it almost works:

```
<rpc-reply>
  <configuration changed-seconds="1450987515" changed-localtime="2015-12-24 20:05:15 UTC">
    <routing-instances>
      <instance>
        <interface/>
        <protocols>
          <ospf>
            <area>
              <interface/>
            </area>
          </ospf>
        </protocols>
      </instance>
    </routing-instances>
  </configuration>
</rpc-reply>
```

I just need the child "`<name>`" for the interesting elements (if there is one there) and bonus if I can somehow get the "`<comment>`" right above "`<interface>`" 
Tried different combinations but not sure how to do it.

Comment: Please define "interesting elements".

Comment: @michael.hor257k The ones in the "whitelist" section, based my solution on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5790798/62138)

Comment: Since `<interface>` is in the WhiteList, should `<name>lo0.1</name>` be in the desired output?

Comment: @unutbu ideally I like to skip that section of interface, but not a strong requirement

Comment: Should it be excluded because its XPath is  `//instance/interface/name` or should it be excluded for some other reason?

Comment: Yep I think I will filter using xpath, already doing some of that before I transform the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just need the child "`<name>`" for the interesting elements (if there
>   is one there)

You could add a template to handle it specifically:

```
<xsl:template match="name[name(..)=document('')/*/ns:WhiteList/*]" priority="1">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

> and bonus if I can somehow get the "`<comment>`" right above
>   "`<interface>`"

Similarly:

```
<xsl:template match="comment[following-sibling::*[1][self::interface]]" priority="1">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

To avoid code repetition, try a more streamlined version:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:ns="match:ns">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<ns:WhiteList>
    <name>area</name>
    <name>interface</name>
    <name>instance</name>
    <name>metric</name>
</ns:WhiteList>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(descendant-or-self::*[name()=document('')/*/ns:WhiteList/*])]"/>

<xsl:template match="name[name(..)=document('')/*/ns:WhiteList/*]" priority="1">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment[following-sibling::*[1][self::interface]]" priority="1">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. What does "priority" do?

Comment: Anyway to have a comment only if its not empty or matches "SOME TEXT" ?

Comment: "*What does "priority" do?*" It resolves conflicts when two or more templates match the same node. Without raising the priority explicitly, the added rules would have the same 0.5 priority as your last template.

Comment: "*Anyway to have a comment only if its not empty or matches "SOME TEXT"*" Sure, just add another predicate.