# XSLT - Include/exclude several tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to make XML handling routine which would remove certain XML tags from XML document given to the routine. The XML document is not fixed but it's known that it is not using any namespaces.

The routine will have two lists of XML tag names:

- tags which should be included after the transformation
- tags which should be excluded after the transformation

Exclude is more dominant i.e. if same tag is in both lists then that tag should not be picked. If parent tag is excluded then child tags should be excluded also.

I have seen great examples and answers accross the web but haven't found fully working solution in single XSLT for my issue.

This solution seems very clear and reasonable but would it be possible to have "BlackList" also in the same XSLT?:
[XSLT - How to keep only wanted elements from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790031/xslt-how-to-keep-only-wanted-elements-from-xml/5790798#5790798)

EDIT: Exclude and include lists are independent from each others. I.e. exclude list does not contain all tags which are not in include list and vice versa.

EDIT2: Simplified process needed: XML -> remove exclude tags -> remove other than include tags.

EDIT3: Fixed link.

EDIT4: Venn Diagrams with all use cases (A section is always wanted):

[image: Venn diagram]

Comment: If you know which elements you want to exclude, why not simply enumerate them directly in the match pattern of an empty template? That would be much simpler and more efficient than any attempt to refer to an external list of element names - whether stored in the XSLT stylesheet itself, or in another document. I am also confused why you would need two lists, with possible contradictions or omissions in-between them. -- P.S. Please state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Tag names are dynamically given and thus are not static. I can generate XSLT/whitelist/blacklist in my code.This is related to certain system interface which returns data in XML SOAP format. External systems can filter data with parameters (include list). Then exclude list is for internal use and maybe not so important at the moment but would like to accomplish abstract solution for the future.

What do you mean with an empty template?

Both versions supported.

Comment: If you can generate the XSLT dynamically, then make it include the *identity transform* template alongside an empty template that looks like this: `<xsl:template match="elemA | elemB | elemC"/>`

Comment: Thank you michael.hor257k but would I then need to know what elements XML document contains? Maybe I would need approach this issue from another direction... However I think I would like to test whitelist&blacklist approach first if someone could provide solution for it.

Comment: "*would I then need to know what elements XML document contains?*" No. All elements not matched by the empty template would be copied (recursively) by the *identity transform* template. Any element matched by the empty template would be suppressed, along with its descendants.

Comment: @michael.hor257k maybe I was unclear but include and exclude lists are independent lists and can contain tag names or can be empty. So if include list is having one tag, it does not mean exclude list would have all tags except that one.

Comment: Added all use cases here, but the original question was about the last one. The other ones are for understading the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***--- answer modified due to clarifications ---***

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="http://example.com/my">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<my:whitelist>
    <item>America</item>
    <item>USA</item>
    <item>California</item>
    <item>LosAngeles</item>
    <item>SanFranciso</item>
    <item>Mexico</item>
    <item>Tijuana</item>
</my:whitelist>

<my:blacklist>
    <item>Mexico</item>
</my:blacklist>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(name()=document('')/*/my:whitelist/item) or name()=document('')/*/my:blacklist/item]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to the following input:

**XML**

```
<America>
   <USA>
      <NewYork>
         <NewYork>no</NewYork>
         <Albany>yes</Albany>
      </NewYork>
      <California>
         <LosAngeles>no</LosAngeles>
         <SanFranciso>no</SanFranciso>
      </California>
   </USA>
   <Canada>
      <Vancouver>no</Vancouver>
      <Montreal>yes</Montreal>
   </Canada>
   <Mexico>
      <Tijuana>no</Tijuana>
   </Mexico>
</America>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<America>
   <USA>
      <California>
         <LosAngeles>no</LosAngeles>
         <SanFranciso>no</SanFranciso>
      </California>
   </USA>
</America>
```

Of course, this only make sense if the two lists are allowed to overlap - i.e. when the blacklist overrides the whitelist.

---

### Added:

If your processor cannot resolve the `document()` function referring back to the stylesheet itself, try the following alternative:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="whitelist">
    <item>America</item>
    <item>USA</item>
    <item>California</item>
    <item>LosAngeles</item>
    <item>SanFranciso</item>
    <item>Mexico</item>
    <item>Tijuana</item>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="blacklist">
    <item>Mexico</item>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:if test="name()=exsl:node-set($whitelist)/item and not (name()=exsl:node-set($blacklist)/item)">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEvk

Comment: Thank you! However is it possible to include WhiteList solution to this same XSLT or do I then need to make another transform with include list?

Comment: As I said earlier, it makes no sense to me to have both an `include` and an `exclude` list. If you have an `exclude` list, than anything not in the list will be included. If you have an `include` list, then anything not in the list will be excluded. If you have both, you have a redundancy in the best case or a contradiction in the worse case.

Comment: There was misunderstanding with this one. Include and exclude lists are independent from each others. Include list is given by external system and exclude list can be used from code to modify "data feed" to skip certain info in certain cases.

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow your explanation. Consider showing a Venn diagram.

Comment: Sorry my english can be little bit confusing :) I try to explain this once again: I have a XML, then I have list of tags which I wan't to removed from the XML and then I have second list of tags which tells tags I only want. So XML -> remove exclude tags -> remove other than include tags.

Comment: Added Venn diagram.

Comment: My problem is not with your English, but with your logic. And your diagram is not clear - please make the `output` section a single, distinct color.

Comment: I added labels there now. Does it make any sense?

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, that most probably will solve it. However I have some problems with that 2.0 version XSLT. Oracle DB XSLT will give some "LPX-00601: Invalid token" errors. Any possibilities to add blacklist also to the 1.0 version solution? I would be very grateful!

Oracle seems give error from this section: select="('NewYork','Canada'). It works if only one variable used, but for some reason it does not like comma separated list there...

Comment: The "some reason" is that XSLT 2.0 is not supported by your processor - contrary to what you said earlier.

Comment: Ok then Oracle documentation was wrong. Thank you again.

Comment: The XSLT does not return anything when I run it from Oracle DB. Also tested with several online XSTL tools e.g. with one from w3schools.com. Is you XSL correct or can there be differences between XSLT engines? Also https://www.w3.org/2005/08/online_xslt/ gave errors with xml and xsl you provided. I also tried to modify your XSL but no success.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to work with online testers, because (from what I have seen) they cannot resolve the `document()` function referring back to the stylesheet itself. as for Oracle, I don't know. I have tested this on various processors, including Xalan (which I think is what Oracle uses). Your question includes a link to another question - does the solution suggested there work for you?

Comment: Your first XSL 1.0 version worked but that was not using document() function. Actually the solution in the link I provided was not also working from Oracle. I didn't tested it fully earlier and assumed I could get it working.

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: @JokkeHeikkilä There is still something that doesn't make sense here: if the two lists are hard-coded into the stylesheet, why are they allowed to overlap? OTOH, if the two lists are dynamic, where are they coming from, and in what format? I suspect you should post another question regarding how to produce a stylesheet from the two lists; in this process you would take the whitelist, remove any blacklisted items, and use the result as the final whitelist.

Comment: Those lists are dynamic and given to routine as array parameters. You are right, I could do that and only use one whitelist! However there are special cases where only another list is given. E.g. if only blacklist is given I need to return all tags except ones in blacklist. That is another case and not described in my original question. Your last solution was not also working in Oracle DB. It's not recognizing node-set at all.

Comment: "*Those lists are dynamic and given to routine as array parameters.*" I am not sure what that means. Perhaps that is the source of the current problem. Have you tried these solutions with the lists hard-coded as shown?

Comment: Yes I have, I haven't even started to develope the routine. I meant lists are given to routine as parameters and thus are dynamic and not hard coded. Now I'm simply using your examples and trying to modify those. Sorry I need to modify my last answer. Of course I need both lists because like said earlier those are independent lists. I.e. whitelist might not even contain tags which are in blacklist. So I cannot "remove any blacklisted items".

Comment: I am afraid I don't have access to the Oracle processor, so I don't know what to suggest. -- P.S. At least in the current scenario, the only items in the blacklist that are of any interest are those that also appear in the whitelist - cf. your Venn diagram.

Comment: Maybe the Oracle processor is old and glumsy for this. If not suitable and performance wise solution found I think I will need to investigate other way to accomplish my idea. I think I need to accept your answer because it seems to be working in online demo you provided. It's currently Oracle engine which cannot be fixed now.

Comment: I still suspect the problem is with your implementation.

Comment: It cannot be with my implementation if Oracle does not recognize node-set. Your first 1.0 solution worked with Oracle and then if I replace XSL from there with your latest solution it throws an error from Oracle DB core.

Comment: There are more differences than just using the function. But if you get a specific error pointing at the EXSLT function, try replacing it with its Xalan alternative (I am assuming the underlying processor is Xalan?).