# Remove all child nodes of a node

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I have a node of DOM document. How can I remove all of its child nodes? For example:

```
<employee> 
     <one/>
     <two/>
     <three/>
 </employee>
```

Becomes:

```
   <employee>
   </employee>
```

I want to remove all child nodes of `employee`.

Comment: Employee `one` and `two` don't have any child nodes.  Have you tried reading in a DOM, changing it and writing out the result?

Comment: I want to remove one ,two itself as they are child of employee

Comment: @Peter, I think he meant removal of all child nodes if employee with `one` and `two` being two instances. @akshay, please post the code that performs (or attempts to) this activity. I simply do not have the time to conjure a full blown example that performs what you need.

Comment: Asked a couple of times on Stackoverflow already. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321860/how-to-remove-elements-from-xml-using-xslt-with-stylesheet-and-xsltproc. Good luck!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    public static void removeAll(Node node) 
    {
        for(Node n : node.getChildNodes())
        {
            if(n.hasChildNodes()) //edit to remove children of children
            {
              removeAll(n);
              node.removeChild(n);
            }
            else
              node.removeChild(n);
        }
    }
}
```

This will remove all the child elements of a Node by passing the employee node in.

Comment: I think he would prefer if you send in the "Employee" node and you just remove all children, in this case if you do that you will remove all employee nodes.

Comment: I realized my mistake after rereading his post, thanks for pointing it out RMT

Comment: BTW, does it needs to be recursive? How this code will works on <employee> 
     <one><one-one/></one></employee>

Comment: I hadn't considered that, but it would be a really easy fix. I edit the solution above.

Comment: Why go through the trouble of removing other children recursively? I don't see anything in the question that would suggest a reason to do that.

Comment: Also, this doesn't compile. One must be very careful modifying it to compile, to not make the same mistake as in leoismyname's answer.

Comment: [`Node#getChildNodes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getChildNodes%28%29) cannot be used with Java's foreach loop because `Node#getChildNodes()` returns a [`NodeList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html) which does not implement the [`java.lang.Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface.

Comment: @DanGetz: That's true.  I made this mistake myself.  [kop's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20810451/4595816) works, though.

Answer (score 57):

No need to remove child nodes of child nodes

```
public static void removeChilds(Node node) {
    while (node.hasChildNodes())
        node.removeChild(node.getFirstChild());
}
```

Comment: If the node list is implemented with an array, it might be more efficient to remove the last child than the first child (which requires shifting the remaining children in the array).

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void removeAllChildren(Node node)
{
  for (Node child; (child = node.getFirstChild()) != null; node.removeChild(child));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
Node result = node.cloneNode(false);
```

As document:

```
Node cloneNode(boolean deep)
deep - If true, recursively clone the subtree under the specified node; if false, clone only the node itself (and its attributes, if it is an Element).
```

Comment: Good idea, but I really think you should write that it creates a copy of the node and that to replace the actual node in the file one should also add node.getParentNode().replaceChild(result, node);

Answer (score -1):

```
private static void removeAllChildNodes(Node node) {
    NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
    int length = childNodes.getLength();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Node childNode = childNodes.item(i);
        if(childNode instanceof Element) {
            if(childNode.hasChildNodes()) {
                removeAllChildNodes(childNode);                
            }        
            node.removeChild(childNode);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why go through the trouble of removing the child nodes' children? Wouldn't just removing the children be enough?

Comment: Also, this can't work right, because you're removing by accessing by index, and going from small to large. So in the example above, first you remove index 0, which is `<one/>`. Then, you remove index 1. However, because `<one/>` has been removed, `<two/>` is at index 0, and `<three/>` is at index 1. So you remove `<three/>`, leaving `<two/>` at index 0. Finally, you try to remove index 2, but there's only one node left in the list, so you get an exception.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void removeAllChildren(Node node) {
    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
    int i = 0;
    do {
        Node item = nodeList.item(i);
        if (item.hasChildNodes()) {
            removeAllChildren(item);
            i--;
        }
        node.removeChild(item);
        i++;
    } while (i < nodeList.getLength());
}
```