# Convert varying xml to another xml

Tags: java, xml, xslt-2.0

I have an input XML file which looks like this:

```
<Root>
 <Monday>Monday<Monday>
 <Indicator>true<Indicator>
 <Value>1<Value>
 <Tuesday>Tuesday<Tuesday>
 <Indicator>true<Indicator>
 <Value>2<Value>
 <Wednesday>Wednesday<Wednesday>
 <Indicator>true<Indicator>
 <Value>3<Value>
</Root>
```

It must be converted to the output XML file which is:

```
<Root>
 <Monday>Monday<Monday>
 <Value>1<Value>
 <Tuesday>Tuesday<Tuesday>
 <Value>2<Value>
 <Wednesday>Wednesday<Wednesday>
 <Value>3<Value>
</Root>
```

The problem is that the input XML can vary. Sometimes it might be

```
<Root>
 <Monday>Monday<Monday>
 <Indicator>true<Indicator>
 <Value>1<Value>
 <Thursday>Thursday<Thursday>
 <Indicator>true<Indicator>
 <Value>4<Value>
</Root>
```

Now the output must be

```
<Root>
 <Monday>Monday<Monday>
 <Value>1<Value>
 <Thursday>Thursday<Thursday>
 <Value>4<Value>
</Root>
```

I also have the list of valid tags like Monday, Tuesday etc, which can come in the input XML in an `ArrayList` in Java. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: The question is not clear. Where do you get you input from? Where do you want to output? The only thing you are doing, as far as I can understand is that you want to remove the `Indicator` tag

Comment: The order of day, indicator, value is fixed? Also, have you tried anything yourself? If not, why not? If yes, show your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

From this answer: [How to remove elements from xml using xslt with stylesheet and xsltproc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321860/how-to-remove-elements-from-xml-using-xslt-with-stylesheet-and-xsltproc) :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Indicator"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you are saying this question is a duplicate, vote to close rather than copying another answer.

Comment: @Raedwald: this is not _exactly_ duplicate. Whether it is simple to find my answer from the original one is the question of OP's XSLT knowledge.

Comment: The question is trivial, so is the answer, and this answer says all that needs to be said.