# Removing elements by name from an HTML document from the shell - Sed command fails

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, html-parsing

I'm trying to remove the embedded CSS from a html file on Linux Server (Red Hat 6.8). 
e.g. 
File 1.htm is as below:

```
abc
<style type="text/css">
whatever
1
2
3
</style>
def
```

And what I need is

```
abc
def
```

I tried the sed command below

```
sed -i 's#<style type="text\/css">(.|\n)*<\/style>##g' 1.htm
```

but it's not working. Could someone shed some light on this? Thanks~

Comment: Another very good tool for this is [**html2text**](http://www.mbayer.de/html2text/). It will handle all html/markdown/css etc..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. html2text is not available on the server for the moment. will try to upload one.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I eventually realized that this question is about _manipulating HTML_ (removing elements from an HTML document), which is why `html2text` (for _extracting plain-text data_) is not the right tool. Aside from that, while `html2text` produces nicely formatted output for _display_, using it to extract data for _programmatic_ processing is problematic.

Comment: @mklement0 I see your point. Based on the content of the question it appears to be asking for a removal that would leave nothing but the plain text (as if you had run `html2text filename`), but in reality if the posted content is a subset of a larger html file, then other wanted elements would be removed as well.

Answer (score 1):

**In order to match *across lines*, you must instruct `sed` to read the *whole file at once***.

With ***GNU* `sed` (Linux) *v4.2.2+***, the simplest way to do that is to **use `-z`** (whose purpose is to read `NUL`-separated records; in the absence of embedded `NUL`s, the entire file is read).

Also, given your **unescaped use of `(` and `)`** as metacharacters, you **must activate support for *extended* regular expressions via the `-r` option**, although you don't strictly need that, because **`(.|\n*)` (which is equivalent to `.*`) must be replaced with `[^<]*` in order to potentially match *multiple* `<style>` elements** individually (`.*`, because `sed` regexes are *greedy*, would match everything up until the *last* `</style>` tag in the file, which would malfunction with multiple elements).

```
sed -z -r -i 's#<style type="text/css">[^<]*</style>\n?##g' 1.htm
```

<sup>Note that I've appended `\n?` to the regex to ensure that no empty line is left behind by the replacement.

Use of unescaped `?` also requires `-r`.

Since you've chosen `#` as the `s` delimiter, you needn't `\`-escape `/` chars. in the regex.</sup>

With **older GNU `sed` versions**, you can use a **loop** (`:a;$!{N;ba}`) to read the entire file at once:

```
sed -r -i ':a;$!{N;ba}; s#<style type="text/css">[^<]*</style>\n?##g' 1.htm
```

Generally, **for a more robust solution, use an HTML/XML-aware tool** such as `xsltproc` (see below).

---

#### Robust solution using XSLT via [`xsltproc`](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html):

`xsltproc` is a third-party utility that comes with **macOS** and *some* Linux distributions (e.g., **Fedora**), and can easily be installed on others (e.g., on **Ubuntu**, with `sudo apt-get install xsltproc`).

With the `--html` option, it is capable of applying [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT)-based transformations to HTML documents too, not just to XML documents.

Here's a sample `bash`-based solution that demonstrates **creating a copy of an HTML document with all `<style>` elements removed**, gratefully adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/322079/45375):

```
# Create a simple sample HTML document with 2 <style> elements at different
# levels of the DOM and save it as "file.html"
cat > file.html <<'EOF'
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      border: 1 solid black;
    }
  </style>
  <p foo='bar'>
    abc def
    <style type="text/css">
      * {
        border: 2 dashed blue;
      }
    </style>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
EOF
```

`xsltproc` can then **apply an XSLT template** to the HTML file (normally, such a template is provided as a file as well, but given its brevity, I'm constructing it in memory and providing it like a file via a `bash` [process substitution (`<(...)`)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)):

```
# Define the XSLT template that copies all nodes in the document except those
# named "style".
# For an explanation, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/322079/45375
template='<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="style"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>'

# Invoke xsltproc with the template and the input file.
# --html tells xlstproc to process the file as HTML, both on input and on output.
xsltproc --html <(echo "$template") file.html
```

The above yields (note how both `<style>` elements were removed):

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head>
<body>

  <p foo="bar">
    abc def

  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

To replace the input file with the modified copy (to emulate `sed -i`), use something like:

```sh
xsltproc --html <(echo "$template") file.html > /tmp/file.$$ && mv /tmp/file.$$ file.html
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `sed` usually process line by line(1 line at a time). In this case,
   We have to read all lines at once. If you are not aware reading all lines at once then you can refer the link.[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed).

   ```
   sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/<style.*<\/style>//' file  | awk 'NF'
   ```

   It will return:

   ```
   abc
   def
   ```
2. Suppose If You have a file like given below:

   ```
   abc
   <style type="text/css">
   whatever
   1
   2
   3
   </style>
   xyz
   <style type="text/css">
   whatever
   1
   2
   3
   </style>
   def
   <style type="text/css">
   whatever
   1
   2
   3
   </style>
   mno
   ```

   And you want to print all text outside to tags then

   ```
    sed '/<style.*>/,/<\/style>/d' file
   ```

   It will return:

   ```
   abc
   xyz
   def
   mno
   ```

Comment: Super cool! this is exactly what I need. It works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @Abhinandanprasad: Thanks for updating (the `\n*` is still unnecessary). I suggest you make it a little clearer that your 1st command handles only a _single_ `style` element, and, on a minor point, that your 2nd command assumes that the opening and closing tags (`<style>`) and (`</style>`) occur only by themselves on a line (are not preceded or followed by text to preserve and do not both occur on a single line).

Comment: @mklement0 I updated. For 2nd command, It's not working if tags are in single line. Any Suggestion how to fix it?

Comment: @Abhinandanprasad: Thanks; as for how to fix the problem of both the start and end tag appearing on the same line (and text preceding/following the tags): see my answer :)

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks  :)