# Copy first N nodes and their children with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML doc with containing a catalog of CDs:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
  <cd><title>Greatest Hits 1999</title><artits>Various Artists</artist></cd>
  <cd><title>Greatest Hits 2000</title></cd>
  <cd><title>Best of Christmas</title></cd>
  <cd><title>Foo</title></cd>
  <cd><title>Bar</title></cd>
  <cd><title>Baz</title></cd>
  <!-- hundreds of additional <cd> nodes -->
</catalog>
```

I want to use XSLT 1.0 to create an excerpt of this XML document, containing only the 1st N `<cd>` nodes, as well as their parent and children. Let's say `N=2`; this means I expect the following output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
  <cd><title>Greatest Hits 1999</title><artits>Various Artists</artist></cd>
  <cd><title>Greatest Hits 2000</title></cd>
</catalog>
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/322079/1296709), from which I adapted the following stylesheet:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="count" select="2"/>

  <!-- Copy everything, except... -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- cd nodes that have a too large index -->
  <xsl:template match="cd[position() &gt;= $count]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I try to apply this stylesheet, I get the following error: `Forbidden variable: position() >= $count`.
When I replace `$count` with the literal `2`, the output contains the full input document, with hundreds of `<cd>` nodes.

How can I get an excerpt from my XML document using XSLT that is still valid XML, but simply throws out a bunch of nodes? I'm looking for a generic-ish solution that also works for document structures that are not quite as plain as my example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="count" select="2"/>

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="cd[position() &lt;= $count]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

If you want to make it generic (which seldom works in practice, because XML documents come in a wide variety of structures), try something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="count" select="2"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[position() &lt;= $count]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```