# use list of columns to use to drive deleting child elements from an xml file

Tags: xslt

I have several sql statements that produce a list of elements that 'should' be columns in a database but are not.
I wish to use these lists to drive transforming an xml file into the same minus various specific children elements that reference those columns.
so for example for TABLE WO I have the list:
'NORMDATE','ORIGRATE','ORIGUNITCOST','PREVRATE','PREVUNITCOST'

I wish to transform this:

```
    <BASE>
<OBJECT>WO</OBJECT>
    <CHILD1>
    <NAME>ONE</NAME>
    </CHILD1>
    <CHILD1>
    <NAME>PREVUNITCOST</NAME>
    </CHILD1>
    <CHILD2>
    <REFNAME>ONE</REFNAME>
    </CHILD2>
    <CHILD2>
    <REFNAME>PREVUNITCOST</REFNAME>
    </CHILD2>
    </BASE>
```

into this:

```
    <BASE>
<OBJECT>WO</OBJECT>
    <CHILD1>
    <NAME>ONE</NAME>
    </CHILD1>
    <CHILD2>
    <REFNAME>ONE</REFNAME>
    </CHILD2>
    </BASE>
```

I'm not sure how to iterate this list which I have to manually prepare to do this - can someone give me a pointer or reference? I assume I use the identity pattern referenced here:
[Text][How to remove elements from xml using xslt with stylesheet and xsltproc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321860/how-to-remove-elements-from-xml-using-xslt-with-stylesheet-and-xsltproc)

my IntelliJ reports this:  Apache Software Foundation (Xalan XSLTC)1.0
I plan on using IntelliJ to transform the data into a usable output file which will be applied later in the target system.

I will not use this in production, but simply to prepare some data that itself will hopefully be usable in my target systems. So this is for a data preparation task.

Comment: Where is this list? Can it be hard-coded into the XSLT stylesheet? Also, does your processor support XSLT 2.0.?

Comment: yes even though it is long I can format it and put in in as part of a variable or expression. I am using IntelliJ but I'm not sure what engine is in use.

Comment: See here how to find out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153

Comment: AFAIK, IntelliJ is an IDE. The real question is which processor will you be using in production.

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Comment: Thanks for checking back. This did not have the desired effect so I am still researching this. My results using this were not xml but a list of strings such as <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    
        
            0
            
            
            -1
            MAXADMIN
            2020-05-29T13:37:09-04:00
            1

Comment: You can see it working here: http://xsltransform.net/pP7NbAw

Comment: It must be old version I am using-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Xalan-J processor, you should be able to take advantage of the [EXSLT `str:tokenize()` extension function](http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html) - for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="exclude-columns">NORMDATE,ORIGRATE,ORIGUNITCOST,PREVRATE,PREVUNITCOST</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/BASE">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(REFNAME = str:tokenize($exclude-columns, ','))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the above assumes all `CHILDn` elements use a `REFNAME` element to reference the column. In your example, some use `REFNAME` and some use `NAME`.